# What happens when the distribution function of a continuous random variable is in the fourth quadrant of the graph?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

### Exercise

An exercise asked me, given a density function $[h(x) = 1/x^2 \Longleftrightarrow x>1]$ of a continuous random variable X, will find and represent the distribution function $ H_X $.

### Solution

Then I calculated $ H_X $ and gave me $ - \dfrac{1} {x} + C $, but the function is different others:

[image]

### Did I do something wrong? Or what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the density is $$\frac1{x^2}, \ x\ge 1$$

Then the distribution function at an $y$ is

$$F(y)=\int_1^y \frac1{x^2}\ dx=-\left[\frac1x\right]_1^y=1-\frac1y, \ y\ge 1.$$

What is wrong with this?

So, you have a definite integral and not a indefinite one!

The following figure depicts the graph of the density and that of the distribution function.

[image]

The blue line is the density and the purple line is the distribution. At an $y$ the value of the purple line tells the area below the blue line from $1$ to that $y$ -- in accordance with the definition of the distribution function and that of the density

$$P(X<y)=\int_1^y\frac1{x^2}dx \ \ .$$

Comment: Being accustomed to the fact that the lower bound was always zero, and that the primitive always gave zero, I omitted Barrow's rule. So the result did not give me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I've added a last sentence to my answer. Pls. read it.